# Access to XMLHttpRequest at firebase getting cors policy error

Tags: reactjs, image-processing, cors, jspdf

I am new to react and am trying to get an image printed to a pdf generated in my system.

However I am getting this error:

[image]

This is my function:

```
pdfGenerate = () =>{
    
     var doc=new jsPDF('landscape','px','a4','false');
     
     var base64Img='https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg'
     doc.addImage(base64Img,'JPEG',65,20,500,400)
     doc.save('CQMS_IMAGES.pdf')
     console.log("Image:"+base64Img);
     
  }
```

This is where I am generating the button for download:

```
<Button style={{float: 'right'}} color="primary" size= "sm" onClick= 
              {this.pdfGenerate}>Download Images</Button>
```

I am getting this error. How to solve it??
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error with your code.
The server at w3schools.com told your browser that the response can only be shown if the same URL is present in the url bar. Which is not. Your site runs on localhost.

To prevent this from happening you can download a no-cors plugin. CorsE (For Firefox) or start Chrome without the CORS-Policy enabled
https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/

Comment: Hi while I see that is correct and it is showing. I just cannot ask a user to diable cors from his windows is there some code that I can write to make this happen?

Comment: No that would be against browser security guidelines. I don´t really get what you are trying to build but... why don´t you host the images to be printed on your own server? With the same domain CORS will not be a problem. Even if its not the same domain, as long as you can write the headers of the returned request, you can make it work.

Comment: when you say write the headers of the returned request. What do you mean?

Comment: If you open your development tools and go to the network tab you will see that every request has a request-header and a response-header. the response-header is set by the server. if you run your own server you can set this response-header yourself.  if you run an apache server you would enable CORS like this: https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/enable-cors-apache-web-server/